# Nesting Futures in Play Action

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Im using Play and have an action in which I want to do two things:-

1. firstly check my cache for a value
2. secondly, call a web service with the value

Since WS API returns a `Future`, I'm using `Action.async`.
My Redis cache module also returns a `Future`.

Assume I'm using another ExecutionContext appropriately for the potentially long running tasks.

Q. Can someone confirm if I'm on the right track by doing the following. I know I have not catered for the Exceptional cases in the below - just keeping it simple for brevity.

```
def token = Action.async { implicit request =>


    // 1. Get Future for read on cache

    val cacheFuture = scala.concurrent.Future {   
        cache.get[String](id)    
    }


    // 2. Map inside cache Future to call web service

    cacheFuture.map { result =>   

        WS.url(url).withQueryString("id" -> result).get().map { response =>
            // process response
            Ok(responseData)
        }

    }

}
```

My concern is that this may not be the most efficient way of doing things because I assume different threads may handle the task of completing each of the Futures.

Any recommendations for a better approach are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not specific to Play. I suggest you have a look at documentations explaining how `Future`s work.

```
val x: Future[FutureOp2ResType] = futureOp1(???).flatMap { res1 => futureOp2(res1, ???) }
```

Or with for-comprehension

```
val x: Future[TypeOfRes] = for {
  res1 <- futureOp1(???)
  res2 <- futureOp2(res1, ???)
  // ...
} yield res
```

As for how the `Future`s are executed (using threads), it depends on which `ExecutionContext` you use (e.g. the global one, the Play one, ...).

> `WS.get` returning a `Future`, it should not be called within `cacheFuture.map`, or it will returns a `Future[Future[...]]`.

Comment: Ok cchantep thanks for the comments. I will do some more digging in the docs and come back if it helped solve my problem.